# REST API: Display Category names in JSON?

Tags: categories, javascript, rest-api, json

Using the Wordpress REST API, I retrieve all my posts into a Angular 6 service.  The category field in the JSON displays the *ID* of the category as an array of numbers.

```
"category": [ 6 ],
```

Is there a way, hopefully on the Wordpress end, to have the API use the category name instead? Or add another node to the JSON?

Comment: Have you read the official [REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/) yet? The linked resource covers exactly this

Comment: Doing this as literally requested would cripple existing code that uses the REST API as it expects IDs it can then pass to the category endpoint

Answer (score -1):

For my needs, I customized the wp rest posts callback:

```
function get_all_posts( $data, $post, $context ) {
    return [
        'id'        => $data->data['id'],
        'date'      => $data->data['date'],
        'date_gmt'  => $data->data['date_gmt'],
        'modified'  => $data->data['modified'],
        'title'     => $data->data['title']['rendered'],
        'content'   => $data->data['content']['rendered'],
        'excerpt'   => $data->data['excerpt']['rendered'],
        'category'  => get_the_category_by_ID( $data->data['categories'][0] ),
        'link'      => $data->data['link'],


    ];
}
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'get_all_posts', 10, 3 );
```

Category endpoint returns directly the name of the post category.

Comment: You can get it within the `_embedded` part of the response when you use the  `_embed` query parameter, so you don't need to modify the response. Explained more in the handbook.

Comment: This code will break plugins and the post editor